# Unique Constraint in Visual Studio SQL Designer

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I was looking at ways to make a newly added column a Unique but not primary column. I had a look at this [W3School link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp). But Instead of following their approach I simply changed my table in the Visual Studio designer as.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Userpro] (
    [Id]                INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Postcode]          NVARCHAR (4)    NULL,
    [Gender]            INT             NULL,
    [Blog]              NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FeedBack]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Username]          NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL Unique,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Notice that I simply added **"Unique"** `[Username] NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL Unique`. I am unsure if this has the same effect or should I go back and just use the script in the link.

Comment: this is the way unique should be used ;)

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the unique constraint will be assigned a random name by SQL Server - which could be an issue if you ever want to drop it via script, or want to compare two copies of the database that both had the constraint added via this script (rather than one being a copy of the other taken after the constraint was created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfect.

Adding `UNIQUE` will have the effect you describe. It is also explained in the link you provide.

Comment: While this will generate a unique constraint, SQL Server will be forced to generate it's name - and that can lead to the problems described in Damien's comment to the question - so now, that is *not* perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the name for the `unique` constraint, then instead of adding the `unique` keyword to your column definition, you can append the full constraint definition to the `CREATE` statement.

The design view will automatically update and you will see `Check_unique_username` listed in the "Keys" section. You can also add it manually to the keys section by right-clicking and choosing "add new" > "unique key" - then use the properties panel to specify the name and column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Userpro] (
    [Id]                INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Postcode]          NVARCHAR (4)    NULL,
    [Gender]            INT             NULL,
    [Blog]              NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FeedBack]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Username]          NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT          [Check_unique_username] UNIQUE ([Username]) -- <-- This line
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```